# php code that saves data to the database and sends an email works on chrome but not safari

Tags: javascript, php

So I have a page that requests visitors to enter their details to get a discount coupon. The form has a submit button that runs php code that sends emails to the visitor and also updates the database with their details. It also fetched a coupon code from the database.

This code works perfectly on chrome but not on safari. On safari the "register-thanks.html" is displayed after submitting the form, but no emails are send and no data is stored in the database.

The code below is in a registration page:

```
                        <form id="formsb" method="POST" name="contactform" action="registration-handler.php" class="contact-form2">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail *">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 margin-bottom-10">
                                        <select class="form-control" type="text" name="subject">
                                            <option disabled selected>How did you hear about Luminicious </option>
                                            <option value="Amazon Search">Amazon Search</option>
                                            <option value="Google Search">Google Search </option>
                                            <option value="Bing Search">Bing Search</option>
                                            <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
                                            <option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
                                            <option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
                                            <option value="Friend or Family">Friend or Family</option>
                                            <option value="Other">Other</option>
                                        </select>


                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 margin-bottom-10">

                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="improve" placeholder="What candlee set would you like us create (colur?,size?,number of candles?) *">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 margin-bottom-10">
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="check"> I am happy to receive emails of offers and new products form luminicious  
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row text-center">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                        <input class="btn-more btn" type="submit" value="SEND ME MY DISCOUNT COUPON" id="email_form">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
```

There is also this javascript to submit the form

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        $(document).on("click", "#email_form", function(event) {
            debugger;
            document.contactform.submit();
            window.location.href = "register-thanks.html";

        });


        var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contactform");
        frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name"); 
        frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email"); 
        frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address"); 
</script>
```

And the php file containing the code to be run when submit button is clicked is here:

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'xxx@yyyyyyy.com';//<-----I removed my email from this
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$improve = $_POST['improve']; 
$check = $_POST['check']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{



    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
    $from = $myemail;
    $to = $myemail;

    // Create connection
    $config = parse_ini_file('/home/xxxxxx/public_html/yyy/db.ini');
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost",$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['db']);
    //$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost",$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['db']);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

        $email_subject = "ERROR connecting to Database / Claim 15";
        $email_body = "No Coupons in Database Table";
        mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    }

    // Insert info of new customer into database
    $sql = "insert into Contacts(Name,Email,Source,Improve,SendUpdates)values('$name','$email_address','$subject','$improve', $check)"; 
    if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {
        $email_subject = "ERROR in PHP Script / Claim discount";
        $email_body = "Error inserting new customer details in Database Table" . $conn->error;
        mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    }

    // Get Coupon Code
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Coupons Where SentFlag = 0 Order By CouponId ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $CouponId = $row["CouponId"];
        $CouponCode = $row["CouponCode"];               


        // Prepare email to be sent to customer
        // Get next Coupon which is not yet sent to customer    
        $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
        $from = $myemail;
        $to = $email_address;
        $email_subject = "Your Luminicious Discount Coupon";
        $email_body = "Welcome to the Luminicious Family......We hope you are enjoying your Candles.".
        " Below is your coupon code. You can use this to buy any of the Luminicious Candles for the next 3 months.".
        " Your Coupon Code is : $CouponCode "; 

        mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

        // Update details of Coupon (set as sent) to database
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $sql = "UPDATE Coupons SET SentFlag = 1, DateSent = '$date', SentToEmail = '$email_address' WHERE CouponId = $CouponId ";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {
            $email_subject = "ERROR in PHP Script / Claim 15";
            $email_body = "Error updating the Coupons Table" . $conn->error;
            mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
        }

    } 
    else {
        $CouponCode = " NONE FOUND - EMAIL NOT SENT"; 

        $email_subject = "ERROR in PHP Script / Claim disc - No Coupons found";
        $email_body = "No Coupons in Database Table";
        mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    }


    // Send email to Luminicious Admin Account  
    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
    $from = $myemail;
    $to = $myemail;
    $email_subject = "New Claim disc registration";
    $email_body = "A new Claim disc registration from: $name".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Source: $subject \n Improve: $improve \n Send Updates: $check \n Coupon Code: $CouponCode"; 

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

    $conn->close();

    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: register-thanks.html');
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration form handler</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
<?php
echo nl2br($errors);
$conn->close();
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery why not refactor your submit JS to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#email_form').click(function() {
        $('#formsb').submit();
    });
});
```

The redirection should only be executed if the submit was successful, remember the Javascript is asynch so the redirection statement in your code above will not wait for the submit to finish.